# Laravel ignore route parameters for assets only

Tags: php, laravel

I have a route that looks for 4 optional parameters. These parameters start at the root of my site like so...

`Route::get('/{category?}/{sub_category?}/{recurring?}/{amount?}', 'PublicController@index');`

The problem I am having is that my local assets are not loading because Laravel is treating my asset paths like parameters to the aforementioned route. What is the correct way to tell Laravel to ignore my assets path `/assets/js/all.js`?

When I look in the console, I see that the HTML page has rendered as my JS file and that is why I am saying that Laravel is accepting my assets path as route parameters.

The HTML content that is rendered as JS is the view that would normally be loaded with route specified.

Comment: If `/assets/js/all.js` located in your application's `public` directory? And is `public` the HTTP server's Document Root?

Comment: @Bogdan Yes and yes.

Comment: That's good, but still Laravel won't interfere with existing directories and files, that comes [pre-configured in the `.htaccess` file](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess#L13-L14), unless you've done something to the file, or Apache is configured to ignore `.htaccess` files, or you're not using Apache at all (in which case please specify what HTTP server you're using and the configuration that is used for serving the Laravel application).

Comment: Also please specify what HTML content is returned instead of the `all.js` file contents.

Comment: @Bogdan I must be missing what your saying. My thoughts are that Laravel us taking the `mysite.com/assets/js/all.js` and using that as a route parameter instead of loading the asset. Make sense?

Comment: @Bogdan Got it! I updated my question to show what is rendered instead of my JS.

Comment: What you're saying makes sense. But that can't happen normally if your HTTP server is configured not to pass request to Laravel's `public/index.php` file if they already exist on disk. For Apache this comes preconfigured with Laravel. So if `assets/js/all.js` exists on disk the HTTP server should serve the file and the request doesn't even reach Laravel.

Comment: You still have not answered what HTTP server you're using?

Comment: @Bogdan Sorry about that. I am using Homestead. I just checked the `.htaccess` and it looks correct. Of course, Homestead uses Nginx but I would assume that it is configured for Laravel since it was created by them. What do you think?

Comment: If you're using Homestead then everything should be running out of the box. And if you access your resource directly in the browser by URL `http://example.com/assets/js/all.js` is still returns the route content instead of the JS file?

Comment: @Bogdan That is correct.

Comment: That's very strange, and if you remove the route definition from Laravel and try accessing the JS file in the browser I assume it works. Either way, please include the nginx configuration file for the app. That's the only place I can think of that this could originate.